# Append Element using DOM manipulation cannot loop through using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to loop through the element that i create using DOM manipulation. it was successfully reflected in the html page but when i loop through in it using queryselector, its not looping. I also tried using getElementByClassName and still not looping.

here is the part of the code which I'm pointing out:

I also attached the whole javascript code with html for reference:

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  createNewOption1();
  createNewOption2();

});

const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
  optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
});

optionsList.forEach(o => {
  o.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  });
});


const createNewOption1 = () => {
  const div1 = document.createElement('div');
  const input1 = document.createElement('input');
  const label1 = document.createElement('label');

  div1.className = 'option';
  input1.type = 'radio';
  input1.className = 'radio';
  input1.name = 'category';

  label1.htmlFor = 'Rejuvenating';
  label1.innerHTML = 'Rejuvenating Set';


  div1.appendChild(input1);
  div1.appendChild(label1);
  optionsContainer.appendChild(div1);
}

const createNewOption2 = () => {
  const div2 = document.createElement('div');
  const input2 = document.createElement('input');
  const label2 = document.createElement('label');

  div2.className = 'option';
  input2.type = 'radio';
  input2.className = 'radio';
  input2.name = 'category';

  label2.htmlFor = 'Maintenance';
  label2.innerHTML = 'Maintenance Set';


  div2.appendChild(input2);
  div2.appendChild(label2);
  optionsContainer.appendChild(div2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Database Project</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d6307e6979.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Sales</h2>

    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">

      </div>
      <div class="selected">
        <p>Select Item</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the options in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener. But you're calling `querySelectorAll(".option")` outside the listener, so the options don't exist yet. Move that code inside the listener.

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  createNewOption1();
  createNewOption2();
  const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
  optionsList.forEach(o => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
      optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });
});

selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
  optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
});

const createNewOption1 = () => {
  const div1 = document.createElement('div');
  const input1 = document.createElement('input');
  const label1 = document.createElement('label');

  div1.className = 'option';
  input1.type = 'radio';
  input1.className = 'radio';
  input1.name = 'category';

  label1.htmlFor = 'Rejuvenating';
  label1.innerHTML = 'Rejuvenating Set';


  div1.appendChild(input1);
  div1.appendChild(label1);
  optionsContainer.appendChild(div1);
}

const createNewOption2 = () => {
  const div2 = document.createElement('div');
  const input2 = document.createElement('input');
  const label2 = document.createElement('label');

  div2.className = 'option';
  input2.type = 'radio';
  input2.className = 'radio';
  input2.name = 'category';

  label2.htmlFor = 'Maintenance';
  label2.innerHTML = 'Maintenance Set';


  div2.appendChild(input2);
  div2.appendChild(label2);
  optionsContainer.appendChild(div2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Database Project</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d6307e6979.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Sales</h2>

    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">

      </div>
      <div class="selected">
        <p>Select Item</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```